# Problems measuring performance of C++ project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, profiling

I am trying to measure the performance of some functions and methods of a console application project in Visual Studio 2010.

I configured the profiling method to instrumentation. The problem is that the performance monitor doesn't work. The message that I get to the output is:

```
Profiling started.
Instrumenting w:\MyProject\ProfilingTest\Build\Debug\ProfilingTest.exe in place
Info VSP3049: Small functions will be excluded from instrumentation.
Microsoft (R) VSInstr Post-Link Instrumentation 10.0.40219 x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
File to Process:
   w:\MyProject\ProfilingTest\Build\Debug\ProfilingTest.exe --> w:\MyProject\ProfilingTest\Build\Debug\ProfilingTest.exe
Original file backed up to w:\MyProject\ProfilingTest\Build\Debug\ProfilingTest.exe.orig
Successfully instrumented file w:\MyProject\ProfilingTest\Build\Debug\ProfilingTest.exe.
The process cannot access the file 'w:\MyProject\ProfilingTest\Build\Debug\ProfilingTest.exe' because it is being used by another process.
Data written to w:\MyProject\ProfilingTest\ProfilingTest110611(17).vsp.
Profiling finished.
File contains no data buffers
File contains no data buffers
Analysis failed
The process cannot access the file 'w:\MyProject\ProfilingTest\Build\Debug\ProfilingTest.exe' because it is being used by another process.
Profiling complete.
```

I presume that the "root of all evil" is:
**The process cannot access the file '...' because it is being used by another process.**

Did anybody faced such problems trying to profile native applications developed in Visual Studio 2010 and solve them?

**Later add:**
If, instead of choosing a project to profile, I am choosing directly the built executable, I succeed to profile, without receiving process blocking, I even received the file analysis. However, the monitoring application is crashing at the end of the profiling. I suspect is related to IDE, but I can't tell for sure.

Comment: Uh, perhaps your anti-virus is interfering?

Comment: Hmmm. It could be. I have to check...

Comment: I added the location on ignored files for antivirus. Still not working.

Comment: Are you running the executable from the profiler or are you running it from the IDE and then trying to use the profiler? ... something else started the app or is using it before you kicked off your profiler.

Comment: I do all the operations from IDE

Comment: I just encountered exactly the same error and found this post.  No solution, but you are not a single one out there.  I did get some numbers by disabling instrumentation and using CPU% sampling method instead, but no matter what, instrumentation would just give me same error you saw (also native C++ project).  And process explorer is useless here because the process is not actually running, this seems to be something internal to VS itself.

Comment: Actually, I tried last evening to instrument the executable directly, instead of instrument the project (from the wizard). It worked. I suspect that IDE is blocking the exe file while monitoring. What happens in both cases is that, after the execution ends, the performance monitor from Visual Studio crashes.

Answer (score 10):

from the performance wizard choose executable as your target and give the path to the executable. This solved problem for me.

Comment: This is what I eventually did (check my last comment to my question). As it looks, I am not the only one encountering this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653)'s find handle feature (ctrl + F) to figure out which process has ProfilingTest.exe open. That'll get you to the next step of the troubleshooting process.

Comment: Haven't tried it before, but procmon (also from sysinternals) might give you the same information in realtime..

Answer (score 0):

Another work-around that I found was to do the following:

```
1) Launch performance wizard
2) choose your project
3) un-check the box to automatically start your profiling 
4) Choose "New Performance Session" and choose your project again (top button on Performance explorer window)
5) Select your performance session from "Targets" and choose "Start Profiling"
```

I wonder if the nice folks at Redmond have taken notice of this..

Regards.